# How to test if a sequence is iid U(0,1)?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, autocorrelation, independence

I have a sequence of time-stamped numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive. They are not residuals from fitting any time series model: they are just raw data. I would like to test that they are (a) uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, and (b) independent.

What is the most powerful way of doing this? Currently I am thinking of using Ljung-Box to test for autocorrelation, McLeod-Li for autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity and Kolmogorov-Smirnov for overall CDF.

Also, for simplicity, I would prefer a single test if possible, since this is going into our continuous integration tests and will have to be interpreted by non statisticians.

Comment: There are many ways in which a series may be non-independent, and non-uniform, and consequently there are many tests that may be used when interested in both (e.g. many dozens of tests may typically be used when testing random number generators -- but there, it's possible to generate millions of observations, more than enough to support a large collection of tests while hopefully bounding the overall type I error rate and still having power to detect small sample sizes). It would be difficult to design a single test statistic to be sensitive to all of these).

Comment: If you don't have huge sample sizes, you may be better off to consider the kinds of deviations from independence and uniformity you most need to identify and focus on those (while avoiding testing almost the same thing with two very similar tests). If your tests are independent, or nearly so, it's relatively simple to combine them to give a single p-value, but even without that, If you limit the number of tests you can bound the type I error rate. It may also be important to consider (especially if you do have access to large samples)  ,,, ctd

Comment: ctd... whether you're really interested in *any* deviation from the null, no matter how small, or whether the question is more of the kind 'are these very close to iid standard uniform?', which requires a different kind of approach.